# How to run container from image build from tar?

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, boot2docker

I have imported java:8 images from tarball using below command,

`cat softwares/jdk-8.tar.gz | docker import - java:8`

and the image is created successfully as below

`REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
 java                8                   2e54a3ae451d        20 minutes ago      376MB`

then I ran the command,
`docker run -it java:8 bash`, it is giving the following error

`docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH".`

Can anyone help me What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Was you able to run `bash` in this container before you export it?

Comment: Yes.  what do we do with bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a valid image. What you are getting is a file system with the java package being extracted and mounted on the root filesystem.

The error is justified and it tells you that bash is not available in this image. The [examples](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/#examples) given in the docker documentation for the import command, are about **importing a docker image that is packaged not a random package of a software source**. If you want java in a container use the [already avaiable java images](https://hub.docker.com/_/java/).